# Problema de boot usb para intalar ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Hola no soy un usuario que conoce de esto pero si me prestan una ayuda les agradesco mucho.
Quise intalar desde un pendrive un sistema operativo ubunto y creo que salio todo mal  ya que no importa lo que haga me aparece esto.

> Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot divice and press a key.

Comment: Esta pregunta se basa en opiniones.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  parece ser consistente con la temática del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta reiniciando la computadora, apenas encienda y muestre la primer pantalla, **presiona F8 o escape o suprimir** (*cualquiera de estas teclas se usa para acceder a la BIOS, varía de placa madre a placa madre*) una vez que este en la BIOS busca la opción que diga **BOOT** en la parte superior, dentro de esta pestaña busca Boot Device Priority( o algo similar) das enter selecciona tu disco duro o ssd donde tengas instalado el Sistema operativo Como **1st Boot Device** das enter y luego regresa a la pantalla BOOT presionando la tecla escape, Busca Hard Disk Drives y haz lo mismo selecciona el Disco duro donde instalaste el sistema operativo Como **1st Drive** das enter, sal (con escape) Luego presiona **F10** para guardar cambios y salir o busca la opción **Guardar Cambios y Salir**, esto hará que tu pc se reinicie y debería de iniciar el sistema operativo, espero esto te sirva de ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

también soy nuevo en la comunidad. Para ayudarte primero necesito saber cual fue el proceso que seguiste, hay que tener en cuenta que para realizar la instalación de linux **DUAL BOOT** en una pc es el siguiente:

- Bootear en un USB la imagen iso de la distribución de GNU/Linux que deseas.
- Apagar tu equipo, conectar el USB booteable y apretar el boton para seleccionar con que se inicia

> puedes buscarlo en internet colocando la marca o modelo de tu equipo
>   junto con seleccion de encendido usb boot

- Seguir los pasos de instalación, cabe recalcar que tienes que tener una **particion en tu disco duro**, y seleccionar opcion DUALBOOT junto a windows que trae ubuntu si lo deseas instalar junto con win.

De igual manera si ofreces un poco más de información acerca del proceso que seguiste para instalar, me facilitaria para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow y gracias por comentar. Me temo que esta pregunta probablemente acabe cerrada porque es demasiado amplia y/o no esta relacionada con esta web que es de programacion. Ademas tu respuesta no proporciona una respuesta a su problema ya que el usuario no ha especificado que ha intentado/hecho